# Difference between SQLAlchemyUserDatastore and SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-security

What is the difference between SQLAlchemyUserDatastore and SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore while creating a data store?

Answer (score 0):

According to their docstrings in the [Flask-Security](https://flask-security-too.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) package ([here](https://github.com/Flask-Middleware/flask-security/blob/17b6b7aebf11454c60f6a782b04b8882c4af6f94/flask_security/datastore.py#L638) and [here](https://github.com/Flask-Middleware/flask-security/blob/17b6b7aebf11454c60f6a782b04b8882c4af6f94/flask_security/datastore.py#L724))

- `SQLAlchemyUserDatastore` assumes that the Flask-SQLAlchemy package is being used for database transactions
- `SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore` assumes that vanilla SQLAlchemy is being used.